# SQL Server service takes more memory and how to find which user session/process is taking more memory?

Tags: sql-server, database, service

SQL Server service in my environment takes more memory and I need to find which process takes more memory and wants to kill it. We tried to find using the below query but the value in SQL server service and value returned from the query is not matching.

```
SELECT spid,
       RTRIM(status) AS Status,
       SUSER_SNAME(sid) AS [User],
       RTRIM(hostname) AS Host,
       RTRIM(program_name) AS Program,
       memusage * 8 AS memusage,
       cpu,
       physical_io,
       blocked,
       CASE WHEN sysprocesses.dbid = 0 THEN '-' ELSE DB_NAME(sysprocesses.dbid)END AS [Database],
       cmd,
       last_batch,
       login_time,
       net_library,
       loginame,
       h.text,
       waittime,
       lastwaittype,
       waitresource
FROM master..sysprocesses
     LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections dmexec ON dmexec.session_id = spid
     OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(dmexec.most_recent_sql_handle) h
WHERE hostname != '';
```

Comment: Please start to use whitespace and line breaks when writing code. A single line of SQL that long is impossible for anyone to read.

Comment: As for why SQL Server is using a lot of memory, SQL Server will use up to 90% (or 95%, can't recall off the top of my head) of your hosts memory, or whatever the instance maximum is (whichever is lower). For Standard, that's 128GB, and Enterprise it's 2TB. What have you set your instance's max memory to?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes we have set max memory and we are aware that SQL server uses maximum memory we configured. We need to split the up the memory usage process/session wise.

Comment: If you are using Enterprise, you could look at the [Resource Governor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/resource-governor?view=sql-server-ver15), however, there is no such functionality in lower editions.

Comment: Is there any way to get this memory usage split up using T-SQL?

Comment: "killing" a task doesn't free any memory on the host system; your chasing your tail here. Limit the instance memory, like I said.